# cannot view Yii app on Heroku after successful deployment

Tags: heroku, deployment, yii2

I was able to successfully deploy my Yii2 app to Heroku from my Github repo. However, when I try to access the domain provided by Heroku (https://portfolio-php.herokuapp.com) I get an error saying "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server." My build logs are provided below. Can someone please offer any guidance?

```
-----> PHP app detected
-----> Resolved 'composer.lock' requirement for PHP to version 5.6.14.
-----> Installing system packages...
   - PHP 5.6.14
   - Apache 2.4.17
   - Nginx 1.8.0
-----> Installing PHP extensions...
   - mbstring (composer.lock; bundled)
   - zend-opcache (automatic; bundled)
-----> Installing dependencies...
   NOTICE: Using '/composer.phar' to install dependencies.
   Composer version 1.0-dev (9e67bc761be98b45875855003eb8b2f23f4bf5a5) 2015-09-18 14:32:06
   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Installing dependencies from lock file
     - Installing yiisoft/yii2-composer (2.0.3)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing bower-asset/jquery (2.1.4)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing bower-asset/jquery.inputmask (3.1.63)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing bower-asset/punycode (v1.3.2)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing bower-asset/yii2-pjax (v2.0.4)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing cebe/markdown (1.1.0)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.6.0)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.6)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing bower-asset/bootstrap (v3.3.5)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap (2.0.4)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.1)
       Loading from cache

     - Installing yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer (2.0.4)
       Loading from cache

   Generating optimized autoload files
-----> Preparing runtime environment...
       NOTICE: No Procfile, using 'web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2'.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 80.9MB
-----> Launching... done, v12
       https://portfolio-php.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

I am using the basic Yii2 template. There is no htaccess file and the config file reads:

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'gfWIx3XdsOCYeUve6VVm1KF4VayT0z7t',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

Comment: Are you using basic or advanced template? What do you have in your htaccess file? and config file? Please, post more info.

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply. I am using the basic template. I do not believe there is an .htaccess file. The config file reads:

Comment: Just added more info to original post including config file content.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is called *basic*, this url should work:

https://portfolio-php.herokuapp.com/*basic*/web

**How to get the basic app working in domain/**

1) Move all files from /web directory to public_html or whatever

2) Put the rest of files in the upper level, so you get something like that:

```
[...]
commands
config
controllers
models
web (empty)
...
public_html
 - assets
 - index.php
 - css
 - [...]
```

3) Change the index.php you've moved to /public_html and change paths to config files, vendor, etc.

4) Create an .htaccess in this directory with the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
```

====

**Update**

Check if https://portfolio-php.herokuapp.com/basic/requirements.php works, If not, you should reinstall all composer dependencies:

- Backup your vendor folder and composer.lock
- Delete all files in vendor folder
- Do `composer install --prefer-dist`

Comment: I  will do what you said in order to get it working in the domain but in the meantime I get a blank page when I try to access https://portfolio-php.herokuapp.com/basic/web. Any reason why that may be?

Comment: Check file permissions. Also enable debug in index.php:

`defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: file permissions look good when I ran `chmod` and as you can see in the below screenshot debug is enabled.  http://prntscr.com/8rrfa6

Comment: Yii2 is not working:

https://portfolio-php.herokuapp.com/basic/requirements.php

Delete files in vendor folder, and reinstall all the composer requirements with: `php composer.phar install --prefer-dist`

Complete steps here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/660/what-to-do-when-composer-fails-to-update-your-vendor-packages/

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help but still no luck after reinstalling composer :(   http://prntscr.com/8s0wvj  and http://prntscr.com/8s0y58

Comment: Also, I just tried creating a new Yii "basic" project and still same issue.. https://yii-basic.herokuapp.com/ . It displays fine on https://yii-basic-dfmmalaw.c9.io/basic/web/index.php . Frustrating as hell!

Comment: @DeanFriedland Read again the steps to install basic yii2 app (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html) and check you didn't forget any step.

Comment: I documented my efforts in the below doc. Would you mind taking a look? I believe everthing was done correctly. https://docs.google.com/document/d/13SlexYLWUyCv2TQcRB2iyOukNyeeXyWgtTJOzdGwRDY/edit

Comment: Hi, @DeanFriedland I've read the document, but the contact form in https://yii-basic-dfmmalaw.c9.io works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. It works now. The answer was the following:

"Your application is in the folder `basic`. That itself should be the repository. You instead put the parent folder of `basic` under version control, which means all the paths in Yii are wrong as you at some point tried moving composer.json up one level.

When you follow the instructions in the Yii manual, you need to `cd basic/` after you created the project.

You also need to remove the dev/debug stuff from the top of web/index.php:

```
// defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
// defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

and add `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` to your project's composer.json.

Then it all works just fine"